# How to save installer file while downloading from ubuntu software center?

Tags: installation, downloads

Can anyone tell me (if this is possible) how can I save the installer file of a software which I download via Ubuntu software center...
I'm new to Ubuntu so give me answer that is understood by me.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu uses deb archives and when you download to install from Software Center all the packages are cached on `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Basically what you need to do is to copy it somewhere else or in an external backup drive. So in your folder navigate to `/var/cache/apt/archive`. You can do this doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and typing the location and just copy all the *.deb packages to somewhere else.

Other than that if you are cozy with command line you can just do:

```
cp -r /var/cache/apt/archives /your/destination
```

Your destination should be writable, i.e you should be able to make folder and files on the location where you copy the debs.

If you want to install softwares on another Ubuntu you can just do `sudo cp -r /you/destination/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives`.

Answer (score 3):

Downloaded packages are automatically saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install those app you should type this command for it:

```
sudo cp -r /you/destination/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives.
```

But I'm wondering if this command will install all of the applications in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try to download APTonCD. Though it is the same as what they mention above :D

Site: http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

> **What is APTonCD?**
>
> APTonCD is a tool with a graphical interface which allows you to
>   create one or more CDs or DVDs (you choose the type of media) with all
>   of the packages you've downloaded via APT-GET or APTITUDE, creating a
>   removable repository that you can use on other computers. APTonCD will
>   also allow you to automatically create media with all of your .deb
>   packages located in one especific repository, so that you can install
>   them into your computers without the need for an internet connection.